# Switching git tags/branches for a local shallow copy

Tags: git

I'm trying to switch from one tag/branch to another in a local shallow git repository. Yet I am noticing some weird behavior.

```
# Initial creation of the repository

git init localrepo
git fetch --no-tag --depth 1 <repo-url> <branch/tag>
git checkout -b shallow --no-track FETCH_HEAD
```

---

```
# Switching to a new branch/tag

git fetch --no-tag --depth 1 <repo-url> <branch/tag>
git reset --hard FETCH_HEAD
```

I am not sure if this is the correct way - yet I noticed something strange. In the file `.git/shallow` revisions start piling up as I switch to new branches/tags.

Is there a way to somehow reset the ```.git/shallow`` file or is there something else missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, Git clones the entire repository and therefore has a complete list of all the objects.  With a shallow clone, the repository contains revisions back to one or more shallow points, and the approach you're using creates a new shallow point.

So what you're seeing is that Git is tracking that in each of those cases, it has the objects only back to those shallow points.  If you removed the shallow points, your repository would be missing objects it was supposed to have, so you don't want to remove them.

Git is not designed to delete objects that are referenced, so as long as you have something in your repository (including the reflog) referencing those objects, they won't be pruned.  If you desperately need your local repository to be as small as possible, you'll need to perform a fresh shallow clone.  Otherwise, there's no harm in the current approach (other than the inefficiency of fetching into a shallow clone) and you're probably fine.